# Can Shark bodies be preserved?

Tags: marine-biology, palaeontology

Under normal conditions, Shark bodies, which are made of cartilage are not preserved and only the teeth can only be preserved. I searched whether Shark bodies can be preserved in ice and I got this CNN article link about a megamouth shark. I'm guessing this was washed up or something, its preserved in ice at the Smithsonian.

I think sharks could encounter ice or some other preservative material and get trapped, like frozen saltwater, iceberg, or amber. So is there a definitive answer if shark bodies can get preserved in such material?
**UPDATE**
I realized frozen salt water would not be a preservative because sharks don't live near the polar seas and ocean, but that does not rule out the possibility of shark catching a current, because warm currents spread out to the poles, and cold water spread out to the equator.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=can+amber+be+found+on+the+ocean+floor&rlz=1CASFJY_enUS951&oq=can+amber+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l8.3723j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on

Comment: Do you mean preserved by some natural means, or by humans?  For the latter, you might read the rather amusing book "The $12 Million Stuffed Shark": https://us.macmillan.com/books/9780230620599

Comment: Natural Preservation.

Comment: Ahem, [greenland shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenland_shark) locations...

Comment: Now I really want a shark preserved in amber… d***!

Comment: define preserved, there are plenty of whole body shark fossils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if they are in very cold, low oxygen waters. Fossils of manta rays are fairly common, and there are examples of complete shark fossils preserved [by silt and limestone.](https://www.google.com/search?q=best%20shark%20fossil&sxsrf=ALiCzsZDBxM4Z3F6S6uGZWBOhk6k4uacuA:1657198075251&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ7eP05-b4AhXSxYUKHeFyAMYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=683&bih=332&dpr=3.75)

Sharks can also be curated using epoxy, formaldehyde, alcohol and other preserving substances. There are famous preserved sharks, one is called Rosie, a great white from Australia, and the other is by Damian Hurst, a tiger shark.